# How to implement dynamic web blacklists in ISA Server 2006?

Tags: proxy, isa-server, blacklist

I'm looking for a way to implement web site blacklisting in ISA server 2006.

I know how to manually define a destination set and block access to it, and I also know how to import XML lists.

What I'm looking for is some publicly available and actively updated blacklist (i.e. "porn sites", or "gamble sites") from some trustworthy source, and for a way to automatically get updated versions when they are released and use them in ISA.

Can this be done, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this is useless now that we have native support for blacklists with ForeFront TMG...

Didn't find any way to do it, though.